# Can you please tell me why my stored proc is not displaying any message?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Please take a look at the following stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetList]
                             @fname nvarchar(50),
                             @lname nvarchar(50),
                             @dob   nvarchar(50),
                             @txtGroup varchar(50),
                             @Msg  VARCHAR(1000) OUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.

IF exists(SELECT 'AKRON' AS CodeName, a.voter_id AS voter_id_vre, a.cnty_Group, a.district_combo, a.voter_fname, a.voter_mname, a.voter_lname, a.voter_suffix, COALESCE(a.str_number,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_suffix,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_apt,'') AS res_addr,
                a.str_city, 'OH' AS str_state, a.str_zip, COALESCE(a.mail_str_num,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_srt_suff,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_apt,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_city,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_state,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_zip,'') AS mail_address, a.dob, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.voter_record_supp WHERE dbo.voter_record_supp.voter_ID = a.voter_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.voter_record a LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.voter_record_supp b ON a.voter_id=b.voter_id
                WHERE a.voter_fname Like '%fname%' And a.voter_lname Like '%@lname%' And a.dob = @dob 
                AND voter_status IN ('A','I') AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'ML%' AND  cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'PA%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'MP%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CH%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'SC%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CP%')
 BEGIN
     SET @Msg = Participants in Group' + @txtGroup + 'are not eligible to participate in this event'
  SELECT @Msg AS 'User'
  RETURN
END
```

When I attempted to execute the above stored proc with the following code below, it always returns a value of NULL.

```
DECLARE @Msg varchar(1000)

EXEC    [dbo].[SP_GetList]
        @fname = N'Jenny',
        @lname = N'Craig',
        @dob = N'04/02/1956',
        @txtGroup = N'DD06A',
        @Msg = @Msg OUTPUT

SELECT  @Msg as N'@Msg'


GO
```

We are expecting to either see the followng message:

Participants in Group `DD06A` are not eligible to participate in this event

or the user who is eligible to participate.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for that piece of advise @marc_s. I will make the change as noted later once I can get this stuff working right.

Comment: There's no way that that `SET` command would compile.  Could you please correct the typo's and make sure that the code presented is accurate?  --thnx

Comment: @RBarryYoung, if you meant the missing single quote, it has been corrected.

I still will like to see the message if condition is not met as specified in the WHERE clause.

This shouldn't be this hard, except for me.

Comment: Still looks wrong to me.

Comment: Either I completely misread the question or you forgot to add `else set @msg = 'user is eligible ...`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, No, you didn't misread the question.

The issue is that with or without the ELSE, no message is displaying.

All that is displaying is '@Msg' with value of NULL.

Comment: Fine. In this case some variable you are concatenating is probably null, resulting in `@msg` being null. Can you please confirm that?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, No. If I run just the query and in the WHERE clause, I give the user a legitimate first name, last name and dob, as long as the user's status is EITHER is 'A' or 'I' and as long as that user is not in any of the groups in the LIKE statement, I get results.

If I try a user who is in that group, I get null and that's exactly what I want.

So for, whether the user is in that group or not, I get null.

My *guess* is the query calling the stored proc is wrong but you experts know better. That's why I came to you.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am eventually going to invoke the stored proc using my .net app but I want to make it is working correctly before I call it with .net app.

Comment: For one, this line is incorrect: `SELECT  @Msg as N'@Msg'`. You cannot enclose variable in apostrophes and expect it to be evaluated. This should read `select cast(@Msg as nvarchar(1000))`. If you can invest ten minutes into helping me helping you you might set up an example at [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) including tables, some example data and stored procedure code.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, wow, that did!

How come I never received any error about not declaring @Msg?

I declared it at the proc level and I thought that was enough!

Please enter your answer in such that you get credit.

The only doubt I have now though and I hope you can answer this is that how come my message is mixed up?

For instance, the code says IF EXISTS(select ...)

I run it now after the last fix, it says, Users in this group can participate. 

My hope is that users in that group cannot participate. Not the other way round. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change your `like`s as per @Jonysuise's answer?

Comment: On the other hand you might be missing something like `and a.cnty_Group = @txtGroup` - this variable is not used in query.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, yes I did make the change as soon as he proposed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print your query, it seems there is no result with these conditions.

Also `like '%@lname%'` seems not correct. you should use `like '%' + @lname + '%'`.
Same with the rest of your parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetList]
                             @fname nvarchar(50),
                             @lname nvarchar(50),
                             @dob   nvarchar(50),
                             @txtGroup varchar(50),
                             @Msg  VARCHAR(1000) OUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.

IF exists(SELECT 'AKRON' AS CodeName, a.voter_id AS voter_id_vre, a.cnty_Group, a.district_combo, a.voter_fname, a.voter_mname, a.voter_lname, a.voter_suffix, COALESCE(a.str_number,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_suffix,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_apt,'') AS res_addr,
                a.str_city, 'OH' AS str_state, a.str_zip, COALESCE(a.mail_str_num,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_srt_suff,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_apt,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_city,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_state,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_zip,'') AS mail_address, a.dob, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.voter_record_supp WHERE dbo.voter_record_supp.voter_ID = a.voter_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.voter_record a LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.voter_record_supp b ON a.voter_id=b.voter_id
                WHERE a.voter_fname Like '%' + @fname + '%' And a.voter_lname Like '%' + @lname + '%' And a.dob = @dob 
                AND voter_status IN ('A','I') AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'ML%' AND  cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'PA%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'MP%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CH%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'SC%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CP%')
 BEGIN
     SET @Msg = 'Participants in Group' + @txtGroup + 'are not eligible to participate in this event'
  SELECT @Msg AS 'User'
  RETURN
END
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.

What do you mean by `Print my query`

Comment: you can print what your query actually looks like. print 'select....from....where...' before your if.

Comment: I did that and I am getting the records I expect when I use a name that meets the requirements as well as name that doesn't.

So, besides the minor issues you corrected (thanks again), I still can't figure out why the execute code isn't emitting the right message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key word **RETURN** is not needed here..... Try exactly the same code without the RETURN key word.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetList]
                             @fname nvarchar(50),
                             @lname nvarchar(50),
                             @dob   nvarchar(50),
                             @txtGroup varchar(50),
                             @Msg  VARCHAR(1000) OUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.

IF exists(SELECT 'AKRON' AS CodeName, a.voter_id AS voter_id_vre, a.cnty_Group, a.district_combo, a.voter_fname, a.voter_mname, a.voter_lname, a.voter_suffix, COALESCE(a.str_number,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_suffix,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.str_apt,'') AS res_addr,
                a.str_city, 'OH' AS str_state, a.str_zip, COALESCE(a.mail_str_num,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_str_name,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_srt_suff,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_apt,'')+' '+COALESCE(a.mail_city,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_state,'')+'   '+COALESCE(a.mail_zip,'') AS mail_address, a.dob, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.voter_record_supp WHERE dbo.voter_record_supp.voter_ID = a.voter_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.voter_record a LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.voter_record_supp b ON a.voter_id=b.voter_id
                WHERE a.voter_fname Like '%fname%' And a.voter_lname Like '%@lname%' And a.dob = @dob 
                AND voter_status IN ('A','I') AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'ML%' AND  cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'PA%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'MP%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CH%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'SC%' AND cnty_Group NOT LIKE 'CP%')
 BEGIN
     SET @Msg = Participants in Group' + @txtGroup + 'are not eligible to participate in this event
END
```

The key word RETURN is used to terminate Execution of the code

Comment: I removed the RETURN keyword but I still can't see the message that I am expecting to see.

Jonysuise, even putting the quotes still doesn't show the message when I intentionally test with records that are supposed to expose the message.